# RegEx find all XML tags

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

How do I match all the beginning tags in an XML document with RegEx? I just need to collect the tag names used.

This is what I have:

```
(?<=<)(.*?)((?= \/>)|(?=>))
```

this matches all the beginning and closing tags.

Example:

```
<Habazutty>yaddayadda</Habazutty>
<Vogons />
<Targ>blahblah</Targ>
```

Above code matches:

```
Habazutty
/Habazutty
Vogons
Targ
/Targ
```

I only need

```
Habazutty
Vogons
Targ
```

I couldn't figure out a way to exclude the closing tags. Negative lookahead didn't work - found nothing. I must have messed up.

Comment: Care to comment on downvoting both answers and the question? Anything that needs improvement? Or just on a random rage trip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change `(?<=<)(.*?)((?= \/>)|(?=>))` to `(?<=<)([^\/]*?)((?= \/>)|(?=>))`, i.e. instead of using `(.*?)` for the tag name, use `([^\/]*?)`. `/` is not allowed in tag names anyway.

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this simply using:

```
<([^\/>]+)[\/]*>
```

The group capture will have your output

Comment: Very nice, thank you! You missed an escape before the last / though, should be `<([^\/>]+)[\/]*>`

Comment: This needlessly matches XML comments and whitespace and does not work for tags with attributes. In my answer I show regular expression without these flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution:

```
((?=<)(?!<\/)<)(.*?)((?= \/>)|(?=>))
```

Basically this `((?=<)(?!<\/)<)` looks behind everything that is "<" `(?=<)` and not "< /" `(?!<\/)`.

@Redneb's answer is cleaner though, less capturing groups and shorter and fancier.

Comment: Also this negative look behind is probably expensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<([^ >!\/]+)[^>]*>
```

matches `test2`, `test3` and `test5` in

```
<!--test-->
<test2>
<test3 x="1">
</test4>
<test5 />
```